# Laravel 5.5 Error: "Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Middleware' not found"

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I'm having a strange problem with a Middleware inserction.

Here's my error:

```
"Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Middleware' not found"
```

And here's my code:

**At app/Http/Middleware/AppVariables.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AppVariables extends Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        ...
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**At app/Http/Kenrel.php**

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\AppVariables::class,
    ];
    ...
```

I've tryed to make `composer dump-autoload`, search on Google and here... Nothing helped. I believe it must be a dumb thing that I just forgot.

Comment: How you solve that issue ?

Comment: have you added your middleware inside the $middlewareGroups instead?

Answer (score -1):

This line is the problem:

```
class AppVariables extends Middleware
```

It will look for `Middleware` in the same namesace, if you don't import it.

Solution: remove the `extends Middleware`:

```
class AppVariables
```

Comment: Removing `extends Middleware` is not really a good idea if you plan on using the class as middleware. Other framework code is relying on middlewares to extend from this base class.

Comment: That is not correct. Middleware does not need to extend `Middleware`. When you create middleware using `php artisan make:middleware` it does not extend any class and neither does the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` default Laravel middleware.

Comment: You are right, my bad. Could have sworn there is a base class available. Actually it seems weird that there is no base class or interface in place which ensures the middleware has the required methods.

Comment: My guess  is OP just copied something like EncryptCookies which extends `Middleware`, which is an alias EncryptCookies: `use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies as Middleware;`

Comment: Hey @devk, you are absolutely right. In the sprint I totally forgot about this detail, I knew it was a dumb mistake.

Comment: We've all been there hehe. I've just defaulted to using laravel's `php artisan make:something` whenever possible

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to extend middleware.

Read the official [document once](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#defining-middleware)